# Pnp Provisioning

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-provision, azure-functions

I have successfully followed (well almost got this working) this [blog](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52486.office-365-auto-provision-site-assets-in-sharepoint-online-using-pnp-provisioning-templatesmicrosoft-flow-and-azure-functions.aspx), however I am stuck as I do not understand if i have 6 different site templates how to pick the one to apply.  This is all feeding off a SharePoint list that we are using for Site Creation.  In the list we have the department which matches the template that should be applied.

Do I need to create multiple functions?  I do not know the next steps for this?

Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, we need to create six different functions, just create a single function in Azure and dynamically handle the parameters. And the function must have a **site template parameter** along with other site metadata (parameters like title, URL, owner, etc).

In your site creation configuration list one choice column should be "Select Template" where all six templates name should be as choice values. While users fill out this list form, they must select the template for that site from the dropdown list. Once the user submits this form through the power Automate(Microsoft Flow) it will go to the Azure queue, now in the Azure function pass all the parameters came from the SharePoint list - so, basically, it is needed only one Azure function.

Notes :

- All the six PnP site templates should be copied to the Azure local drive, so based on the template in the Azure function, you need to apply the appropriate PnP template.

**Update - how to implement the above approache - SharePoint Online site provisioning using Microsoft Flow, Azure Functions and Azure Storage Queue?**

**High-level steps as use cases:**

1. The user creates an item in a SharePoint list.
2. Microsoft Flow will be triggered on item creation.
3. Microsoft Flow will add a message on the Azure Storage Queue.
4. The Azure Function will monitor the Azure Storage Queue and create
   the subsite based on the values entered in the SharePoint list using
   PowerShell.

In order to achieve the above use case - we need to follow the below steps:

- Create SharePoint List
- Get and register AppId and AppSecret in SharePoint Online
- Create Azure Storage Queue
- Create Azure Function
- Create PowerShell Script
- Test Azure Storage Queue
- Create Microsoft Flow

In the Azure function, we need to write the below PowerShell code:

```
$requestBody = Get-Content $triggerInput -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$ParentSiteUrl = "https://spfire.sharepoint.com/sites/projectsitecreation/"

$WebTemplate = $requestBody.WebTemplate

$SiteTitle = $requestBody.SiteTitle

$SiteDescription = "Site with PowerShell"

$SiteURL = $requestBody.SiteURL

$SiteLanguage = $requestBody.SiteLanguage

$AppId = $env:AppId

$AppSecret = $env:AppSecret

connect-PnPOnline -AppId $AppId -AppSecret $AppSecret -url $ParentSiteUrl

New-PnPWeb -Title $SiteTitle -url $SiteURL -Locale $SiteLanguage -Template $WebTemplate -Description $SiteDescription

Write-Output "PowerShell script processed queue message '$requestBody'"
```

For the step by step details, refer to the below article - very well explained about the above use case:

[SharePoint Online site provisioning using Microsoft Flow, Azure Functions and Azure Storage Queue](https://www.sharepointfire.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-pnp-site-provisioning-using-flow-and-azure-function/)

**How to dynamically apply PnP-Provisioning template to the site?**

Let's say you have three templates **template 1**, **template 2**, **template 3**  these will be in SharePoint custom list choice column value (**template selection**)... user will select any of the names of the templates from the SharePoint list.... then with the same name copy the actual three different templates in the **Azure local drive like template1.xml, template2.xml,template3.xml**.

Now create the site as the usual way using the PnP command, then finally call Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate command and template name in the pathname should be dynamic which is coming from sp list... So if the user selects template 1 from the sp list, you need to pass this template name which is located at Azure local drive in the Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate command.

**Example: Post site creation step:**

If the user selects **template1** from the SharePoint list template selection choice column, then we need to call the **Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate** like below:

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "Azure DrivePath Where this template is located""\template1.xml"
```

If the user selects **template2** from the SharePoint list template selection choice column, then we need to call the **Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate** like below:

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "Azure DrivePath Where this template is located""\template2.xml"
```

If the user selects **template3** from the SharePoint list template selection choice column, then we need to call the **Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate** like below:

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "Azure DrivePath Where this template is located""\template3.xml"
```

Comment: That is awesome news, so here is what I am showing in my run.ps1 script in azure {
"callbackUrl":"",
   "Title":"sitetitle",
   "Url":"siteurl",
   "Owner":"siteowner",
   "Template":"STS#3"

}
When the whole script runs it gets stuck doing two things, 1st is applying the template and the 2nd is writing back to the original list it fails

Comment: I would also like to run an additional script to put all of the system site collection admin into the new site as well.  can i just add that?

Comment: For your first query - first create the blank site, then apply the PnP Provisioning template... I am not clear about your second part of that question "writing back to original list" For your second question - applying PnP provisioning template to system site collection - if this is one time job, no conditional events to execute, then you just execute that script from your local machine itself, no need of Azure function.

Comment: Part of the original instructions included in the blog I am following writes back the status to the Site Creation list in SharePoint.  However I keep getting an error that it cant find the list Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot contact site at the specified URL /sites/SiteCreation/Lists/SiteCreation. There is no Web named "/sites/SiteCreation/Lists/SiteCreation/_vti_bin/sites.asmx"." and it never applies the template.  It creates the site but doesnt do the rest?

Comment: Also when I look at the xml it is not including all of the lists or the branding in the template....do these have to be applied seperatly?  Sorry I just do not have experience doing this and appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi - Refer this MSDN article where it explained about all types of parameters we can pass in Get-PnPProvisoning template like which are the lists to include or exclude: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Hi - answer updated - please refer to this article, it has been explained the steps in very well - https://www.sharepointfire.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-pnp-site-provisioning-using-flow-and-azure-function/

Comment: Thank you for additional link to review, this doesnt help me understand how to call the different templates it should pull this information from the list i am not sure how to tell it to do that. Here is the script I am using but it is only getting as far as creating the site but it is not applying the template and i have to hard code the template in, how do i make the call to pull the correct one?

Comment: I added a picture of the code i am trying to use

Comment: Any additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Dorinda explained, please refer to the updated answer "How to dynamically apply PnP-Provisioning template to the site?" section

Comment: So to apply the template I have to have the same name in my dropdown in the list?  Meaning if i have a selection in my list called Providers, but the template is called providers.xml do i have to have the providers.xml in the sharepoint list to call it?  The end user is not going to know what that means?  Also do i add the apply at the end of the above script?  and how do i change to that new url so that it is applied correctly.  I am sorry I am new to this and dont want to make unwanted mistakes.  Thank you!!!!

Comment: Any update on this question?

Comment: You can friendlier name in the SharePoint list for the template... but you need to pick the correct template from the code. For example, in the list u can give something template as service provider.. but in the code you need to apply the template if template is service provider then get this PnP template like wise... at the end of the script you need call this.. I would suggest, if this long discussed answer helped u, you can close this answer and start a new question as this thread is getting nested. :-)

Comment: I am sorry this is getting so long but I am getting errors from what was provided and still not sure of how to adapt this to use.  I am running out of time and appreciate your continued effort to help me.